# Why double ampersand chained conditions runs in background together the last one?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, process-management

I have some conditions for some background job to run:

```
condition-command && condition-command && background-job &
```

The problem is: I want the conditions to block until the job runs, as if I had run:

```
condition-command; condition-command; background-job &
```

But it isn't a condition, if previous command fails I do not want the job to run.

I realised it is asynchronous, but it should not, in my mind the both following scripts should be the same, but they do not:

```
sleep 2; echo foo & sleep 1; echo bar; wait   # prints foo, then bar: correct
sleep 2 && echo foo & sleep 1; echo bar; wait # prints bar, then foo: bug
```

I know if I test `$?` variable it would work, or if I put the last one inside a subshell (but then I would lost job controls, I want to avoid daemons), but I want to know why bash make it this way, where is it documented? Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

**Edit:** Chained `if`s is disgusting, that is why I will not accept it as a alternative way.
**Edit 2:** I know a subshell is possible, but it will not work for me, let us imagine I want to run a bunch of commands then `wait` in the end. It will be possible if i check the existence of `/proc/$PID` directory, but it would be a pain in the neck if there are several jobs.
**Edit 3:** The main question is WHY bash does it, where is it documented? Whether or not it has a solution is a bonus!

Comment: In your example is foo supposed to be a background job?

Comment: @Seth, yes, it will increase performance if I run in parallel what I am able to.

Comment: `I know a subshell is possible, but it will not work for me [...]`. Your last command will start at subshell anyway, from `bash` manual: `If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.`

Comment: Yeah, but it's a subshell whose PID and job no. are known to the current shell: `(background-job&)` leaves it completely detached

Comment: How about using `{}` then: `{ background-job& }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the background to apply to the whole line, then use `eval`:

```
sleep 2 && eval 'sleep 10 &'
```

Now only the second command will be a background job, and it will be a proper background job that you can `wait` on.

Comment: It is subshell, the last one will become a daemon. If you read till the end my question, I already knew this would be possible, but I cannot dispose the job controls, see **Edit 2**

Comment: @TiagoPimenta, ahh, I see now... edited with fix.

Comment: While this simple example works, `eval` is absolutely not the right tool.

Comment: @Gilles, why not?  Got a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

After your edit: the issue is that `&&` has higher precedence than `&`, so the whole thing binds together into an `AND list`, and gets backgrounded as a unit. See [Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) in the manual, although it isn't enormously clear.

The smallest change to your original code that would work is

```
if condition-command && condition-command; then background-job & fi
```

(it *is* an `if`, but not a chained one).

---

Just

```
condition-command && condition-command && (background-job &)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It is subshell, the last one will become a daemon. If you read till the end my question, I already knew this would be possible, but I cannot dispose the job controls, see **Edit 2**

Answer (score 2):

[This is essentially jimmij's comment, turned into an answer.]

You can use `{ }` to override the normal operator precedence, without creating a subshell like `( )` would. So use:

```
condition-command && condition-command && { background-job & }
```

And similarly for the `sleep`/`echo` example:

```
sleep 2 && { echo foo & }; sleep 1; echo bar; wait # prints foo, then bar: correct
```

Note that `{` and `}` are shell keywords, not metacharacters like `(` and `)`, so you need a space between `{` and the command inside it (so it's not treated as part of the command name), and a command terminator like `&` or `;` before the `}` (so it's not treated as just another argument). Also, if there's another command after `}` you need a semicolon (or other command delimiter) between them.