# What happens when we use ampersand `&` at the end of the pipeline?

Tags: shell, scripting, pipe, syntax

Normally, when we use a pipe, the operations on the left and right of the pipe are run in separate subprocesses. The outputs of the first command are transmitted as input to the second command. In this case, I thought that when I used the ampersand sign at the end of the pipeline, only the second operation would be started in the background. However, when I tested it, the entire command is launched in the background.

In the following use, I expect the second command is started in the background, but the entire command is started in the background. I tested in bash.

`cmd | cmd2 &`

What exactly did I know wrong or missed?
What happens when we use ampersand `&` at the end of the pipeline?

Comment: Pretty much the same reason as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169289/70524 - precedence.

Comment: What sense does it make to run just part of a pipeline in the background? You need to wait for the first command to finish anyway, so backgrounding the last command would only let the shell continue for the (generally short, and maybe nonexistent) interval between when the first command in the pipeline finished and when the second one did.

Comment: @AndyDalton That's not correct; it waits for all processes in the pipeline to exit (unless you background the pipeline). Try `sleep 5 | echo foo` -- it'll print "foo" immediately, but you won't get a new prompt for 5 seconds.

Comment: @GordonDavisson interesting, nice example.  I stand corrected.